# Getting null reference exception calling stored proc

Tags: c#, asp.net, nullreferenceexception

I run code that produces a datatable.  From this datatable, I gleen the State & CRID. I use these pieces of information to run code to get the PRID. Problem is, every time I run this, I get a Null Reference Exception.  I've tried declaring  int PRID = 0 before running the code; however, I then end up with 0 as my answer every time.  I've executed the code in SQLServer 2008 using the same parameters, and I get the correct result.
I am unable to determine why this code is not running correctly.

```
    public int GetPRID(int RRID, string State, int PCID)
    {
        try
        {

            SQLCON = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SQLCON.Open();
            SQLCmd = new SqlCommand("spGetPRID", SQLCON);
            SQLCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@RRID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = RRID;
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@State", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = State;
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@PCID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PCID;

            int PRID = (Int32)SQLCmd.ExecuteScalar();
            return PRID;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/ErrorRedirect.aspx?" + ex.Message, false);
            return 0;
        }
        finally
        {
            SQLCON.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: On which line do you get the exception? This should give you (and us) a clue.

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: int PRID = (Int32)SQLCmd.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: Are you return your primary key id???

please check it.

or add return @@Identity in this line your stored procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.  It wasn't in my C# code - it was within the SQL itself.  I was declaring @PRID as int, and asking it to return @PRID.

Once I removed this, it worked fine. Thank you all for your contributions.

Answer (score 2):

This line is problematic here

```
  int PRID = (Int32)SQLCmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

of course I can't know the result of your stored procedure, but [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) could return NULL and if this is the case the cast to Int32 will fail with the error `null reference exception`

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

> Returns the first column of the first row in the result set, or a null
>   reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) if the result set is empty

So the correct approach if there is a possibility to get a null as return value is

```
  object result = SQLCmd.ExecuteScalar();
  if(result != null)
      PRID = Convert.ToInt32(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

From memory `SQLCmd.ExecuteScalar()` will return null if no value is returned, which will give you a null reference exception.  If a value is returned but the value is a database null it will return BDNull.value, which will also fail because it can't be cast to an int32.

Comment: when I execute from within SQL, the result is 2.

Comment: Use SQL profiler to see what query is resulting from your code, it may be different from what you are using to test, e.g. a parameter may be different.  The call to ExecuteScaler is clearly returning null.

Comment: Thanks, Ben.  Your first comment led me back to the SQL code itself, which assisted me in finding the problem.